# SQL count display 0s using 1 table

Tags: sql

I have a table called requests, and Im looking to count how many requests where the column rideId is not null each day during the last week. I have the following query:

```
Select count(*), dayname(time) as Day
from request
where time >= (select current_timestamp - interval 7 day) and rideId is not null
group by dayname(time)
order by dayofweek(Day);
```

How can I make it so it shows me those days where there is no request with rideId and count should be 0

Table is: Request(userId, time, rideId)

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Comment: Did you just try to remove "rideID is not null" condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the not null check into your count, and join to a calendar table to bring in the missing days.

```
SELECT
    t1.dname,
    COALESCE(t2.numRides, 0) AS numRides
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Monday' AS dname, 2 AS dow UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Tuesday',   3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Wednesday', 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Thursday',  5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Friday',    6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Saturday',  7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sunday',    1
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DAYNAME(time) AS dname, COUNT(rideId) AS numRides
    FROM request
    WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    GROUP BY DAYNAME(time)
) t2
    ON t1.dname = t2.dname
ORDER BY t1.dow;
```

Comment: If there is no request in a day, that day won't be in the result set,right?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.day, coalesce(b.cnt, 0) as cnt
from (--select all days here) a
left join
(select dayname(time) as day, count(*) as cnt
  from requests
  where some_condition 
  group by day) b
 using a.day = b.day
 order by day;
```

Comment: What about the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Oh.. Yeah.. I missed it.. Edited my answer